# Design decision regarding std::array fill

Tags: c++, c++11

`std::array` in C++11 is a useful class that provides a C++ Container interface over a C stack array.

But why does `std::array` not have the typical fill constructor that most containers have? Instead, it has a method `fill`.

Is there some reason why `std::array` is unique among STL containers in this regard?

Comment: Because otherwise std::array wouldn't be a POD anymore.

Comment: I thought C++11 relaxed the definition of POD

Comment: @Channel72: POD: *"A POD struct is a non-union class that is both a __trivial class__ and a standard-layout class [...]"*. trivial class: *"A trivial class is a class that has a default constructor (12.1), has no __non-trivial default constructors__, and is trivially copyable."* However, `std::array` is an aggregate, and such have to follow similar rules (see Borgleader's answer).

Answer (score 6):

From section 23.3.2.1:

> An array is an aggregate (8.5.1) that can be initialized with the syntax
>   array a = { initializer-list };

If it worked like `std::vector` it wouldn't be a POD anymore. Additionally from the same section:

> The conditions for an aggregate (8.5.1) shall be met.

These conditions are:

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors (12.1), no brace-or-equalinitializers
>   for non-static data members (9.2), no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11),
>   no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).

Answer (score 5):

Yes; `std::array` is meant to be an aggregate (C++11 §8.5.1) so that at can be used in as many contexts as possible where a plain array can be used. An aggregate can have no explicit constructors or destructor.

Answer (score 3):

Everybody's explained the "why" pretty well I think, so I'll just put up a workaround suggestion, which should compile to be just as good as a native constructor:

```
template< typename T, std::size_t n > std::array<T,n> filledArray( const T& v ) {
    std::array<T,n> r;
    r.fill( v );
    return r;
}

auto arr = filledArray<int,4>( 7 );
```

Comment: Hm, any reason for not using a for-range loop? Just curious.

Comment: Or the `fill` member function?

Comment: also @Zeta, only because I keep forgetting it exists. Changed to use `fill` because it makes more sense and is more likely to have optimisations.

Comment: @Dave: Completely forgot `fill()` during the discussion about PODs and aggregates, doh.